# Appending a custom element inside a custom element results in hidden element

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

Why can I not append a custom element to another custom element? Well, I can, but the result is the child element is now hidden. I don't understand because I am not appending it to the parent's shadow DOM or something.

https://jsfiddle.net/qehoLf8k/1/

HTML

```
<template id="text">
  <style>
    .text {
      color:red;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
</template>

<template id="page">
  <style>
    :host {
      border:5px solid green;
      display: block;
      margin:20px;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
    }
  </style>
  This is a page
</template>

<div id="my-body"></div>
```

JS

```
class Text extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const template = document.getElementById('text');
    const node = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(node);
  }
}
customElements.define('my-text', Text);

class Page extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const template = document.getElementById('page');
    const node = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(node);
  }
}
customElements.define('my-page', Page);

const body = document.getElementById('my-body')
const page = document.createElement('my-page')
const text = document.createElement('my-text')

// Not working, element is hidden
page.appendChild(text)
body.appendChild(page)

// Working
//body.appendChild(text)
```

Result: cannot see the `<my-text>` inside `<my-page>`. My intentions would be to append any amount of `<my-text>` elements into the `<my-page>` element.

[Inspector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyiqI.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're using the Shadow DOM you should use a `<slot>` element to indicate where the children should go in the template. Otherwise the shadow won't know what to do with the children and will not render them visually.

```html
<template id="page">
  <style>
    :host {
      border:5px solid green;
      display: block;
      margin:20px;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
    }
  </style>
  <slot></slot> <!-- children go here -->
  This is a page
</template>
```

Comment: Hmm. Even though `<my-text>` appears outside of `#shadow-root` in the inspector? Is everything in a `template` the shadow DOM? I thought by calling the classic `appendChild` it would go in to the (light?) DOM.

Comment: That is correct. Your element is indeed appended to the Light DOM. But the visual representation of the element will be dictated by the Shadow DOM. So you have to specify where in the Shadow DOM template the child must appear.

Comment: Just check the inspector and look inside the `<slot>` element. There will be a reference to the element from the Light DOM. The child itself doesn't actually exist in the Shadow DOM, only it's visual representation.

Comment: Ugh... It makes no sense. I've read the docs so many times. I thought I finally understood `<slot>` as a placeholder with a `name` attribute. Then when you declare HTML you can add elements with the same name as `<slot>` and they are essentially "slotted" in accordingly. Now how does just adding a `<slot>` solve everything??!

Comment: When using a `<slot>` without a `name` attribute you allow every child without `slot` attribute to be *slotted* there in the Shadow DOM. You can have multiple named slots and a single unnamed slot to dictate where in your Shadow DOM the elements should be displayed. This way you can create a complex layout in the Shadow DOM and display elements in a *default* (unnamed slot) or specified (named slot) position in that layout.

Comment: you are my savior, thanks. Sorry, couldn't refrain from posting this comment